# Retieve a row from data extension using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, ampscript, dataextensions

Is there a the way to retrieve the row from data extension using API and without needing to specify any of the column names based on the filters.I know we can do that using the AmpScript  but I couldn't  find an documentation for the same using API.

I went through  to [this](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension/) guide for API but it need to specify the exact column names to retrieve  the data . But I want to retrieve the data based on filter and only the name of the data extension.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can get the data extension column names by doing a retrieve of the [**DataExtensionField**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextensionfield.htm) object with a filter on the `DataExtension.CustomerKey` property -- `CustomerKey` being the External Key of the Data Extension.

Here's a sample SOAP envelope, if that helps:

```
<soap:Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
        xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
        <RetrieveRequest>
          <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>
          <Properties>Name</Properties>
          <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>DE_Appointment_Reminder_H2882</Value>
          </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soap:Body>
```